# Java searching option

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have drop down that has list of column name. When user selects column name and enters serach value i populate the page but I am trying to bring everything from table if they dont enter search value but seleted one of the drop down column name. I tried to do this way if search value is null dont look for where clause just go straight to the else but this is not working for me..Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong over here? Thank you

```
sql.append(" SELECT id, name, dept, email");

if ((this.getSearch() != null)&& (this.getSelected().equals("1"))){
    sql.append("  from table ");
    sql.append("  where id = '");
    sql.append(this.getSearch());
    sql.append("'");
}else if ((this.getSearch() != null)&& (this.getSelected().equals("2"))){
    sql.append("  from table ");
    sql.append("  where name = '");
    sql.append(this.getSearch());
    sql.append("'");
}else{
    sql.append("  from table ");
}
```

Comment: Please don't build your query with StringBuilder. This is a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: @claymore1977 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection Use a prepared statement to mitigate some risk.

Comment: StringBuilder isn't really the issue, its the inserting of variables that is the issue.  So a more concise comment would be "Use a PreparedStatement to insert the "this.getSearch()" data.  Outside of that, a person can use String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder... whatever!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `this.getSearch()` does not return `null` but something else like an empty string or a string containing whitespace characters. Have you sanitized that String already?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever dealing with a String returned from some code that i didn't write, I usually check for NULL first and then for a Zero Length String:

```
String str = myClass.getMyString();
if (str == null || str.length() < 1) {
  /* Failure case */
} else {
  /* Success case */
}
```

The above code makes the assumption that the return value methodology states that a zero length string is a mode of failure, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for this, called a debugger.